# pahlcon-devtools can't install on fc16 x64

Tags: phalcon

i get phalcon devtools from github

```
$ cd /opt/myworkdir
$ git clone https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools.git
$ cd phalcon-devtools
$ git checkout -b 0.7.0
$ git pull origin 0.7.0
$  . ./phalcon.sh
```

show this error

Phalcon DevTools (0.7.0 BETA 1)

Error: Incorrect usage

Answer (score 1):

The message "Error: Incorrect usage" is normal, it means that devtools is expecting an action to execute but no additional commands were provided.

Try

```
phalcon commands
```

or

```
phalcon project blog
```

Comment: i don't install, where phalcon?

Comment: it looks like you already have the environment variable $PTOOLSPATH  pointing to some directory in your .bash_profile or .profile, remove it first from that file before install devtools

Comment: phalcon commands , 
phalcon-devtools/phalcon: line 78:  3755 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) php "$PTOOLSPATH/phalcon.php" $*